# How to recover grub with LUKS encrypted LVM partitions after motherboard replaced?

Tags: grub2, lvm, dual-boot, uefi

I had dualboot Windows 10 and Kali Linux x64 (Linux distribution based on Debian 9 x64) on my Lenovo X280 notebook with EFI bios. Windows 10 uses BitLocker with password (not TPM). Linux uses LUKS encryption. I have Kali /boot partition created separately. I had to replaced motherboard in service. After this only Windows boots. Grub was missing. So I tried reinstall grub from Live system (from USB flash drive):

1. I manually encrypted LUKS partitions:

   ```
   cryptsetup luksOpen /dev/nvme0n1p4 disk
   ```
2. I mounted partitions:

   ```
   mount /dev/mapper/sk1-system /mnt
   mount /dev/nvme0n1p5 /mnt/boot
   mount /dev/nvme0n1p1 /mnt/boot/efi
   for i in /dev /dev/pts /proc /sys /run; do mount -B $i /mnt$i; done
   ```
3. Install and update grub:

   ```
   chroot /mnt
   grub-install /dev/nvme0n1 
   update-grub
   ```

After it grub was installed successfully, but after power on notebook I see black screen with LUKS password, when I enter correct password I see only Windows Boot Manager in Grub menu, not Kali Linux.

My drive is partitioned this way:

```
nvme0n1:
nvme0n1p1: EFI
p2: MS Reserved Partition
p3: Windows 10 (BitLocker)
p4: crypto_LUKS partition it contains:
LVM:
/dev/mapper/sk1-system
/dev/mapper/sk1-swap
p5: Kali /boot partition (ext4)
p6: DATA (NTFS)
p7: WinRE_DRV
```

My [grub.cfg](https://pastebin.com/nafHMaZ8)

My [fstab](https://pastebin.com/CGMN0YAc) file

What way I can add boot item for Kali Linux too please? And what way I skip black screen with LUKS password request before grub screen please? (Before motherboard replace I see grub screen directly).

Comment: The prompt for your LUKS password cannot appear until AFTER GRUB boots the Linux kernel. At that point the initrd would run, which is what triggers the LUKS password prompt. Please confirm which EFI boot manager you are booting in to. You can check this in the BIOS settings.

Comment: Hmm, actually, GRUB2 supports LUKS. But given your /boot is not encrypted, I don't see why that feature would be in use. Can you post your `grub.cfg`?

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa Many thanks for help. My grub.cfg https://pastebin.com/nafHMaZ8 and fstab file: https://pastebin.com/CGMN0YAc. In Bios I see boot options: "kali" - this case and "Windows Boot Manager".

Comment: @EmmanuelRosa I have partially solved it with reinstallation of grub-efi https://wiki.debian.org/GrubEFIReinstall, now I see Kali Linux boot item, but still I have to enter LUKS password two times.

Comment: I solved my problem with the steps in your question, thank you muchly for writing so clearly!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reading your `grub.cfg` file, the part that is the immediate cause of the first LUKS password request is this:

```
cryptomount -u 99cc765bd11945e7a922436c76cfd505
set root='lvmid/vlNbhc-Fecj-bwew-vg7J-nnuy-3aCy-zl395m/Co88vm-3aMx-939B-ehD7-ijFW-Hw7p-z3gWUW'
```

So, it looks like `update-grub` is preparing to read something from a LVM-based filesystem. What might that be?

```
font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
```

Oh, it wants to read a font file from /usr/share/grub directly.

According to the comments, this part comes from `/etc/grub.d/00_header` file.
If GRUB internal feature test variable `feature_default_font_path` were set to `y`, then the entire block would be skipped, avoiding the LUKS password prompt here.

Another similar block is immediately after `### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###` comment: it also makes sure the encrypted disk will be mounted, in order to...

```
if background_image /usr/share/desktop-base/kali-theme/grub/grub-16x9.png; then
  set color_normal=white/black
  set color_highlight=black/white
```

... load a background image for the GRUB menu from `/usr/share/desktop-base/`.

The remaining blocks (and the corresponding configuration snippet files in `/etc/grub.d/`) don't seem to depend on access to encrypted disks.

So, to get rid of the extra LUKS prompt before the GRUB menu, you'd need to either disable the graphical menu and fall back to a plainer appearance of GRUB, or look into `/etc/grub.d/00_header` and `/etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme`, find out what configuration options they provide. Then you could copy the appropriate files and use the appropriate options in `/etc/default/grub` to make GRUB find the necessary fonts and images from another location, so GRUB won't need to read an encrypted disk just to display a menu.

It looks like you could copy the font file from `/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2` to e.g. `/boot/grub/unicode.pf2` and then set `GRUB_FONT=/boot/grub/unicode.pf2` in `/etc/default/grub`.

Likewise, you could copy the background file from `/usr/share/desktop-base/kali-theme/grub/grub-16x9.png` to `/boot/grub/grub-16x9.png` and then set `GRUB_BACKGROUND=/boot/grub/grub-16x9.png` in `/etc/default/grub`.

After doing these configurations, you could run `update-grub` and verify that your regenerated GRUB configuration should now be quite a bit simpler, and contain no `cryptmount` commands any more.

Comment: Many thanks! It works perfectly. And I very sorry for my delay.